# How can I iterate all files under a folder but some special sub folders I don't want to iterate?

Tags: c#

For example, I have a folder called Effects, and there are tons of sub folders in it. I don't want to iterate files under Effects/Materials but others I want to iterate. How should I do that?

Comment: If you have a list of names of subfolders you don't want to iterate, then you just can check each subfolder against that list and either skip it if this is in the list or go inside it if not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see below code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IterateItemsInFolder(@"C:\Users\MT\Desktop\Effects");
    }

    public static void IterateItemsInFolder(string path)
    {
        // We ignore Materials folder
        if (Path.GetFileName(path) == "Materials") return;
        // Get all files and directories in direcotry
        var items =  Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(path);
        foreach(var item in items)
        {
            var attr = File.GetAttributes(item);
            // If current item is directory, recurse.
            if (attr.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory))
            {
                IterateItemsInFolder(item);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Skip Directories `StartsWith` or `Contains` or any other logic you want -

```
var directoryToSearch = @"C:\SearchDir\";
var directoryToExclude = @"C:\SearchDir\Exclude";
var files = (from f in Directory.GetFiles(directoryToSearch, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                let directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(f)
                where !directoryName.Contains(directoryToExclude)
                select f).ToList();
return;
```

Comment: It seems not work... I still got the file I don't want to iterate